# On Spark 1.6.0, get org.apache.spark.SparkException related with spark.driver.maxResultSize

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 1401 tasks (1024.3 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

I got this exception while calling on spark-shell

```
sqlContext.cacheTable("TableName")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName").count()
```

I understand that collect() may send big result to driver, but here only count is needed, so I do not understand why 1024.3 MB memory is used. If the table is not cached, then the sql query worked fine without exception.

Comment: I meet the same problem with RDD.sum. Althoguth, increase the spark.driver.maxResultSize solves the problem, I am still puzzled why RDD.sum causes the partition sends huge data(more than 1GB) back to the driver.

Answer (score 2):

I meet this problem when I change table format from textfile to parquet. 
At first the job run faster and well. But after several tries, the driver throw familiar exception :

`Total size of serialized results of 498 tasks (1024.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)` .

With the spark.driver.maxResultSize increasing (2g), I met GC problem:

```
Exception in thread "broadcast-hash-join-9" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.copy(UnsafeRow.java:535)
```

[As the official doc description](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html) :

Having a high limit may cause out-of-memory errors in driver (depends on spark.driver.memory and memory overhead of objects in JVM). Setting a proper limit can protect the driver from out-of-memory errors.

So increase both `maxResultSize` and `memoryOverhead`.